# How to summarise taking a random value from a categorical column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sample, summarize

I have two species and some values for them.

```
values <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
spp <- c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5))
df <- data.frame(spp, values, stringsAsFactor = FALSE)
```

I want to summarise the data frame, grouping by these species. My idea is summarise, getting a random value by species. Using `dplyr` philosophy, I want to do this:

```
n.df <- df %>%
group_by(spp) %>%
summarise(value = sample(value))
```

but the `sample` function isn't working into `summarise`

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I don't know what "My idea is summarise, getting a random value by species."  means.

Comment: `sample(value)` permutes the vector rather than returning a single value. Perhaps you want `sample(value,1)`? Also, you seem to have a typo -- is it `values` or `value`? If the former, you would need `sample(values,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `dplyr` you can also take advantage of `sample_n` function, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(spp) %>%
   sample_n(1)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 2
> # Groups:   spp [2]
>   spp   values
>   <chr>  <dbl>
> 1 a          2
> 2 b          9
> ```

Comment: Thank you, so much!